# uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23

Tags: configuration, openwrt

```
BusyBox v1.28.4 () built-in shell (ash)

  _______                     ________        __
 |       |.-----.-----.-----.|  |  |  |.----.|  |_
 |   -   ||  _  |  -__|     ||  |  |  ||   _||   _|
 |_______||   __|_____|__|__||________||__|  |____|
          |__| W I R E L E S S   F R E E D O M
 -----------------------------------------------------
 OpenWrt 18.06.2, r7676-cddd7b4c77
 -----------------------------------------------------
root@mortar:~# opkg upgrade $(opkg list-upgradable | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
Configuring luci-lib-nixio.
Configuring luci-lib-jsonc.
Configuring luci-base.
Configuring luci-mod-admin-full.
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
Configuring luci-app-firewall.
Configuring luci-proto-ppp.
Configuring luci-proto-ipv6.
Configuring luci.
Configuring luci-ssl.
Configuring luci-app-upnp.
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
```

Helpful :-).  Parse error *in which file*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# cd /etc/config
# uci export 2>&1 | grep -C5 '^uci:'
    option ports '5190'
    option comment 'AOL, iChat, ICQ'

config default
    option target 'Express'
uci: Parse error (section of different type overwrites prior section with same name) at line 12, byte 23
    option proto 'udp'
    option pktsize '-500'

config reclassify
    option target 'Priority'
# grep -r 'config reclassify' .
./qos:config reclassify
# mv qos ~
# uci export 2>&1 | grep -C5 '^uci:'
#
```